# как вывесли на экран все элементы массива long?

Tags: java

У меня есть массив long m[] от 1 до 100000000000. Как его вывести ? (и как с ним работать именно в глобальном плане "узнать размер" и т.д. )
Я написал такой код но он работает только для чисел до максимума int-a.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    long m[] =  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10};

    try {sorter(m);} 
    catch(Exception e) {System.out.println("ошибка");}
}

static void sorter(long m[]) {
    //.length это интовая встрoенная функция ((((
    for (long i=0; i<m.length;i++) {
        System.out.println("число "+ m[(int) i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: количество элементов массива long будет равно максимальному int. ибо памяти твоего компьютера не хватит на это.

Comment: `У меня есть массив long m[] от 1 до 100000000000.`
Это сто гигабайт, если у вас просто массив байтов, а у вас массив `long`, то есть ещё в разы больше.

Answer (score 3):

Если вам надо хранить количество элементов, большех чем `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, то советую вам посмотреть на [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html). Чтобы узнать размер, недостаточно просто вызвать метод `size()`, потому как он ограничен тем же `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Как вариант - завести счетчик, и в итераторе обойти все элементы, инкрементируя этот счетчик:

```
Iterator<Long> iterator = linkedList.iterator();
long count = 0;
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
   iterator.next();
   count++;
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Или же с помощью дефолтного метода [forEachRemaining](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) ( для java8) :

```
AtomicLong count = new AtomicLong(0);
Iterator<Long> iterator = linkedList.iterator();
iterator.forEachRemaining(next -> count.incrementAndGet());
System.out.println(count.get());
```